# Add Facet Labels Y-Axis Label to Non-Facet Plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add the facet labels that appear on the right y-axis to a ggplot that is not a facet.  Is there a simple way to do this?  Plotv2 shows the y-axis labels that I want to add, but I don't actually want to split my data across two facets.  Are there are set theme parameters that can be used to add the second y-axis title easily, or will I have to go about using a custom grob?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

df <- data.frame(
  Position=(c(1:5000)),
  Signal=(c((rep(c(5),times=2000)), (rep(c(100),times=1000)), (rep(c(5),times=2000))))
)

Plotv1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Position, y=Signal, col = "#000000")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip="off") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="MyLegend")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(t=30)),
    legend.title = element_text(colour = "#000000", size=12),
    legend.text = element_text(colour = "#000000", size=12)
  ) +
  annotation_custom(
    grid::segmentsGrob(
      y0 = unit(-25, "pt"),
      y1 = unit(-25, "pt"),
      arrow = arrow(angle=45, type="closed", length=unit(.15, 'cm')),
      gp = grid::gpar(lwd=3, col="#000000", fill="#000000")
    ),
    xmin = 2000,
    xmax = 3000
  )

ggsave(paste("~/Desktop/Plotv1.png", sep = ""), Plotv1, width = 8, height = 1.7)

Plotv2 <- Plotv1 +
  facet_grid(Signal~.)

ggsave(paste("~/Desktop/Plotv2.png", sep = ""), Plotv2, width = 8, height = 1.7)
```

[image: Plotv1]

[image: Plotv2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider adding a redundant facet label, or using a secondary axis to add additional titles on the right:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid("Second Y-Axis Title"~.) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~., breaks = NULL, 
                                         name = "Third Y-Axis Title"))
```

[image]

Comment: No need to add a column to the dataset. You can simply do `facet_grid("Second Y-Axis Title"~.)`.

Comment: Oooh, nice, I'll edit!

Comment: Thank you.  Adding `facet_grid("Second Y-Axis Title"~.) +` did what I needed.